# Ruby oci8 fails when using dotenv for password

Tags: ruby, oci8

I'm attempting to use the dotenv gem to securely store a password for an oci8 connection.  My .env file looks like this:

```
# this file is stored in the same location as config.ru
SCOTT_PASS='tiger'
```

Here's my config.ru file:

```
require 'dashing'

require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load

configure do
  set :auth_token, 'YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'

  helpers do
    def protected!
     # Put any authentication code you want in here.
     # This method is run before accessing any resource.
    end
  end
end

map Sinatra::Application.assets_prefix do
  run Sinatra::Application.sprockets
end

run Sinatra::Application
```

Here's the job which is failing.  It fails with a null password error (ORA-01005).

```
SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do |job|

  conn = OCI8.new('scott', ENV['SCOTT_PASS'], 'orcl')
  cursor = conn.parse("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TABLES")

  cursor.exec

  r = cursor.fetch

  send_event('table_count', { current: r })
  cursor.close
  conn.logoff
end
```

I was able to confirm Dotenv.load is working properly as I was able to set other variables successfully, so there seems to be something unique about the oci8 connection.

I'm new to both Ruby and programming, so I might be overlooking something simple.  Thanks!

Comment: What is this `SCHEDULER` constant? Where is it defined and how is it executed? What relevance has the `config.ru`?

Comment: Ah.  I should have mentioned that this code is part of a dashboard using the dashing framework (https://github.com/Shopify/dashing).  I believe the scheduler portion is just the rufus scheduler component.

The job snippet works correctly when I substitute the actual password instead of ENV['SCOTT_PASS'] so that's the part I'm confused about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a fairly obscure issue, but the root cause was due to a complex password being used (alpha numeric and special characters).  The same password worked correctly in a small ruby script, but fails when placed under the rufus scheduler.  Switching to a 20+ character password without numbers or special characters resolved the issue.  Guessing there might some type of escaping required.